# How do I remove extra space between textField and error message in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a TextFormField with borders. I am using a validator with some conditions to show proper error messages. My error messages are shown exactly below the TextFormField border which is what I want. In my validator, I use an if statement that should return a String, so I have to add `return ''` after the if statement, as shown in my code:

```
TextFormField buildPasswordForm() {
    return TextFormField(
      //key: ValueKey('passwordKey'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
      obscureText: _isHidden,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //labelText: 'Passowrd',
        hintText: 'Password',
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.lock_sharp,
          //color: kTextColor,
        ),
        suffixIcon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(12),
          ),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: inContact,
            onTapUp: outContact,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.remove_red_eye,
              size: 26,
              //color: kTextColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addPasswordError(error: kPasswordNullError);
          return '';
        } else if (value.length < 8) {
          addPasswordError(error: kShortPasswordError);
          return '';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removePasswordError(error: kPasswordNullError);
        } else if (value.length >= 8) {
          removePasswordError(error: kShortPasswordError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (newValue) => password = newValue,
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildEmailForm() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      //autofocus: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //labelText: 'Email',
        hintText: 'Enter your email',
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addEmailError(error: kEmailNullError);
          return "";
        } else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          addEmailError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeEmailError(error: kEmailNullError);
        } else if (emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          emailErrors.remove(kInvalidEmailError);
          addEmailError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (newValue) => email = newValue,
    );
  }
}
```

If I add `return ''`, the space between the error message and the bottom board is added, but if the validation is not satisfied, that is: if neither email nor password entered satisfy requirements, the screen does not go to the next one as it should. If I remove `return ''`, then the space between the error message and the bottom borders disappears, but when I hit continue, wether fields are properly filled or not, the screen just goes to the next one.
I would love to have a solution for, and explanation of this behavior.

[image: What I don't want]

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 0):

in my case is like this i usually separate my validator to a different class

```
  class Validator{
    
    static String email(String value){
    
        String pattern = r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]';
        RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
        if(!regExp.hasMatch(value)) return 'Email is invalid';
        else if(value.isEmpty) return 'Email is Empty';
        else return null;
    }
    
     }
```

then i create a widget for my textformfield and to call the validator like this

```
  CustomTextFieldX(
    obsecure: false,
    hintText: 'Enter your email',
    nameTop: 'Email',
    controller: registerController.emails,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    validators: (value) =>Validator.email(registerController.emails.text = value),
     ),
```

i hope it helps. just comment below if their something to clarify at.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I appreciate it.
I tried your solution but I lost some functionality and the error message came indented to the right.
After some thinking, I just decided to return null (I am not using null safety with this app) and all went well. I still don't get it as the `if` statement should return a `String`.

Comment: After some work, `return null` did not solve the issue. So I am back to square one.